# how to solve a high-dimension system faster, please

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve a high-dimension system as below. If the size is 50, there are 50^2 equations and find the root cost about 6s in my PC. If the size is 100, about 100s. But if size is 500, the time is unrealized and the required memory is bigger than my PC 16GB. I have tried `Compile` and options `Compiled -> True`. There is no obvious improvement. Of course, applying `NSolve` is slower than `FindRoot`. Please, how can I solve a high-dimension system faster?

```
rootCovMat[matA_, sigmaCov_, ε_] := 
  Module[{sol, matSize, matV, equs, matVInt},
    matSize = Length[matA];
    matV = Table[v[i, j], {i, matSize}, {j, matSize}];
    matVInt = Transpose[{Flatten[matV], ConstantArray[0, Length[matV]^2]}];
    equs = 
      Flatten[
        Table[
          ε*Sum[matA[[i, k]]*matV[[k, j]], {k, matSize}] + 
          ε*Sum[matV[[i, k]]*matA[[j, k]], {k, matSize}] + 
          sigmaCov[[i, j]] == 0
        , {i, matSize}, {j, matSize}]];
    sol = FindRoot[equs, matVInt, Compiled -> True];
    Return[sol];];

ε = 1;
matA = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {50, 50}]; 
sigmaCov = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {50, 50}];
matSize = Length[matA];
rootCovMat[matA, sigmaCov, ε] // AbsoluteTiming
```

For example, if you input matrix `A` and `C` whose sizes are 50 x 50, solving the matrix `V` costs about 6s.

Comment: I can't figure out what extra code is needed to get this to actually run.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has a problem that is simply too big for his system to handle

Comment: @m_goldberg. In a more general way I think that the question is: what is the fastest method to solve a matrix equation of the type: A V + V A + C = 0, where A and C are given matrices, while all the matrix elements of V are the variables.

Comment: Are you trying to solve a Lyapunov equation?

Comment: @sebhofer Thank you very much! In fact, it is a Lyapunov equation. The function LyapunovSolve[] is much faster than my old methods!